# Inserting block/braces in If-else statements using JDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm creating an Eclipse plugin that should insert block to one line if-else statements.

[Just like Eclipse facilitates via setting a preference for editor on Save-action]

for e.g.

```java
if (isFormed)
    if (i == 1)
        System.out.println("i is 1");
    else
        System.out.println("i is undefined");
```

should be replaced with

```java
if (isFormed)
{
    if (i == 1)
        {
           System.out.println("i is 1");
        }
    else
        {
        System.out.println("i is undefined");
        }
}
```

Here is how I'm visiting & replacing the statement inside AST

```java
node.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
                @Override
                public boolean visit(IfStatement ifStatement) {
                    //Add Block in case of IfStatemnet if it is not there.
                    if(ifStatement != null){
                        Statement thenStatement = ifStatement.getThenStatement();
                        Statement elseStatement = ifStatement.getElseStatement();
                        String codeToReplace = "if("+ifStatement.getExpression()+")";
                        if(thenStatement instanceof Block)
                            codeToReplace += "\n"+ thenStatement + "";
                        else
                            codeToReplace += "{\n"+ thenStatement + "\n}";
                        if(elseStatement != null){
                            if(elseStatement instanceof Block)
                                codeToReplace += "else" + elseStatement +"\n";
                            else
                                codeToReplace += "else{\n" + elseStatement +"\n}";
                        }
                        replaceStatment(rewriter, getBlockInstence(ifStatement), codeToReplace , ifStatement);
                    }
                    return super.visit(ifStatement);
                }
            });
```

& once it's whole visited I commit the working copy.
This adds block to the outer if-else, & not to the inner ones.

I also tried replacing the document & committing it while visit like below:

```java
IDocument document = new org.eclipse.jface.text.Document(iCompilationUnit.getSource());
TextEdit edits = mCompilationUnit.rewrite(document, null);
document.replace(ifStatement.getStartPosition(), ifStatement.getLength(), codeToReplace);
edits.apply(document);
iCompilationUnit.getBuffer().setContents(document.get());
iCompilationUnit.commitWorkingCopy(true, new NullProgressMonitor());
```

But this adds braces at wrong places for inner if-else & whole code gets messed up as **IT DOES NOT HAVE UPDATED "offset" & "length" FOR THE CODE TO BE REPLACED** & hence it keeps replacing at wrong places & messes up.

//void org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocument.replace(int offset, int length, String textTobeReplaced)

I also tried getting how eclipse is doing it. But couldn't reach that point.
**Can anyone help solving this?** Or any sort of plugin code I should refer? Even if I can get **which eclipse plugin does this** I can try de-compiling it.

Comment: this `node` that you are visiting - is it referring only to the outer `if-else` statement? How do you obtain that `node`?

Comment: First it will visit the outer IfStatement & then it visits the inner one. I retrive all TypeDeclarations of CompilationUnit & I visit all them.

Comment: but aren't references to the inner statements invalidated when you commit the modifications of the outer statement?

Comment: so it's like the reference of the inner statements refers older information like offset & length etc. It's not the updated one.

Comment: so does it help to refresh this information somehow?

Comment: unfortunately it does not refresh the information, the difference is that if I don't commit on every visit then as a result it adds block just for outer if. & if I commit on every visit then it modifies code with wrong/old place|length

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that through changes the offset of expressions was changed and not updated. As a workaround I first collected all expressions that should be replaced, then reversed the collection and so started the changes at the end of the code. So the offset did not changed and I could change all expressions.

It's no good solution, but this worked for me.